# HTML, Javascript: How to share a container under specified bootstrap panels

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="header">
            <div><a href="#" class="navbar-left"></a>
        </div>   
        <div id="content">
             <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                 <li class = "nav-tabs"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
                 <li class = "nav-tabs"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
                 <li class = "nav-tabs"><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
             </ul>
             <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="a">
                       <div class="panel-body">A content</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="b">
                       <div class="panel-body">B content</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="c">
                       <div class="panel-body">C content</div>
                  </div>  
              </div>  
        </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row" id="container"> image </div>
</body>
```

This is the HTML code, I have a three column panel showing A, B and C using bootstrap.

Underneath the content, there is a container with id = "container" at the bottom of all panels.

Here is my question:
I want to only have id = "container" shown under panel A, B. However, I don't want the panel C showing id = "container" . Is there any way to realize this?

Comment: this `id="container"` doesn't have content any elements or control. Can you explain your logic?

Comment: This container is controlled by elements in A and B, not C. This container is a svg object generated by other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the class for the all '''li''' items

```
class = "nav-tabs"
```

Second, we need to add '''$(document).ready(function()''' to refresh the page, thus the "class" will be updated

```
$(".nav-tabs").on( "click", function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    bindClick();
    })
});

function bindClick(){
    if ( $("#c").hasClass("active")){
        $("#container").hide()
    } else {    
        $("#container").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Hide()`

```
 <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#c").hide();
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. I would like to hide #container in #c. This code will hide #c, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery:

```
$("#c").hasClass("active") {
    $("#container").hide()
} else {
    $("#container").show()
}
```

Or if you prefer a more CSS method:

```
$("#c").hasClass("active") {
    $("#container").css("visibility", "hidden")
} else {
    $("#container").css("visibility", "visible")
}
```

Comment: This looks like will be working. I will try this tomorrow from my lab computer. Will get back to you tomorrow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Bmillerz, I have tried this. active -> "active". However, this doesn't work. I don't know why. After I select the panel, the class for #c shows "tab-pane active". However, this can not hide the container.

Comment: @YingWang did you try `$("#c").hasClass("active") {`

Comment: Yes, I tried. I think the problem is when I select tab C, the class for #c  was changed in the browser. However, the ($('#c').hasClass("active") == false. I am so confused.

Here is the code I tried:
'''
 if ($('#c').hasClass("active")) {
    $('#container').hide()
} else {
    $('#container').show()
};
'''